# Automatic label modification in ggplot graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am have a `data.frame` of mutations and their frequences in subset of the genes. The `data.frame` looks like:

```
a <- read.csv(text="gene,frequency,mutation,position
geneA,0.5,C > T,183
geneB,0.2,+T,22
geneC,0.3,A > G,539", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I have plotted the graph with ggplot2:

```
    pie <- ggplot(a, aes(x="", y=frequency, fill=gene))+
       geom_col(width = 1)+
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue","yellow"))+
       coord_polar("y", start=0, direction = -1)
```

[image: pie_plot]
Now I would like to mark the mutations in labels on the graph as they are in literature: *geneA*<sup>c.183 C > T</sup>. And here I started to have a problem. I need to transform values in character vectors, then merge them and add to the graph

function like

```
expression(paste(italic(a$gene), ^"c.", ^a$position, ^a$mutation))
```

does not work. I tried to use `apply` function with no success as well. Could you help me to find solution for this?

Comment: How exactly do you want to place these labels on the graph?

Comment: You can make the expressions you want with `as.expression(Map(function(a,b,c) substitute(italic(a)^{paste("c.", b, " ",c)}, list(a=a, b=b, c=c)), a=a$gene, b=a$position, c=a$mutation))`, i'm just not sure what you want to do with them after you've made them.

Comment: I would like to plot them inside the sectors of the pie and in the legend on the right side from the graph

Comment: Thank you, expression is working now

Comment: @MrFlick could I somehow rewrite results from the expression into a new character vector?

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you mean by that or why you would want to do that.

Comment: I have realised that `a$gene` column have duplicates values (some genes mutated several times) so in the end it corrups the pie plot if I build plot like `pie <- ggplot(a, aes(x="", y=frequency, fill=gene))+ geom_col(width = 1)+ scale_fill_manual(values=coloring, labels = substitute(italic(a)^{paste("c.", b, " ",c)}, list(a=a, b=b, c=c)), a=a$gene, b=a$position, c=a$mutation)))+ coord_polar("y", start=0, direction = -1)`

So I tried to use instead `fill=row.names(a)` but then I cannot use expression anymore